# How to load new interstial ad after the ad is shown in new Interstial API Admob

Tags: android, admob

There was onAdClosed() method in previous Admob Interstial Ad API but I'm confused how do I load Ad again after it is shown in the new API as described [here in new API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/interstitial/InterstitialAd).

```
        FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback = new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                mInterstitialAd = null;

            }
        };
    InterstitialAdLoadCallback interstitialAdLoadCallback=new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd ad) {

            mInterstitialAd = ad;

            mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError adError) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }
    };

    InterstitialAd.load(KeyboardActivity.this, Constants.INTERSTIAL_AD_UNIT_ID,
            new AdRequest.Builder().build(), interstitialAdLoadCallback);
```

How do I load the new ad when the interstial ad is shown?

Comment: `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()`callback method is similar to `onAdClosed()` callback. So maybe  you can move your code there